# Where do I find my boot menu?

Tags: bios

I want to know where the boot menu is on my ASUS laptop.  Can anyone tell me where to find it or where to find my BIOS settings?  I am having trouble booting my computer to ubuntu with a USB.

Comment: What is your laptop model no.?

Comment: UEFI/BIOS Boot keys - about halfway down on this Microsoft page
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12911.tips-for-configuring-your-bios-settings-to-work-with-windows-to-go.aspx

Comment: idk where do i find it?

Comment: Did you even read the two answers you got to this question?  Those two basically explain how to get to it.

Answer (score 2):

Depends of model but normally you access the BIOS using:

- <kbd>F1</kbd>
- <kbd>F2</kbd>
- <kbd>F10</kbd>
- <kbd>Delete</kbd>
- <kbd>F12</kbd>
- <kbd>F8</kbd>

You should check when you boot for the exact key.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the model of you machine, you could plug in the USB, to boot from it, during the post press the <kbd>F12</kbd> key and see if you get an option to select the USB drive.

Another way is to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> key at the ASUS splash screen. A popup menu will appear with all the devices that can potentially be used for booting, select the desired device and press Enter. (you may have to hold the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key)