# Basics on Installing

Tags: system-installation

I just downloaded version 12 and after finding out that I had to burn the ISO to a CD (my Win XP computer did not have any burning software on it), when I insert the disc it just wants to run a demo. I want to do a full install (totally replace WinXP and have only Ubuntu). What's the trick?

EDIT: My PC is a clone, built in 2006 by a local PC shop, has an AMD Athlon processor and a Benq CD drive. It runs really slow using Windows XP. I have previous experience with some older PCs - I have installed Ubuntu in the past (I think it was version 10) and it breathed new life into them. I even used one of them for writing an article comparing OpenOffice to MS Office and did a little Drupal development work on it, even after it seemed the computer was essentially dead with Windows.

Anyway, it looks like it is too old to upgrade to Ubuntu so I am giving up on this. Thanks for all of your help. If there is any way to close this post, please feel free to do so.

Comment: Thanks - I looked at that link and it does not address my problem.

Comment: it does address your problem. You need to necessarily create an installation media outside your hard drive to install Ubuntu. In the step 7. you can select wiping out your hard drive with the "Replace Windows ..." option.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. My PC fails at step 5. I cannot boot from the CD. I just need an installation file. I guess that does not exist.

Comment: There's no installation file. Ubuntu is installed like any other OS, using an installation media. Check this [question](http://askubuntu.com/q/335866/169736) for help about how to show your boot menu. It would be awesome too if you [edit] your question and include your PC model.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you created is a LiveCD. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD under "Using your LiveCD"

Comment: Thanks. I don't want LiveCD. I want to permanently install Ubuntu and wipe out Windows forever. I don't want to dual boot. Is there a way to do that? Note: my pc does not boot using the Ubuntu disc even after installing the tool that is supposed to help with that. A simple .exe file would work best for me, but I will try anything.

Comment: Although technically correct, your answer does not address the OP's problem. Also, it is essentially a link, and this site is better suited with full answers that does not depend on links that can possibly expire or become outdated.

Comment: Sorry for my thickness, but the LiveCD link seems to be focused on demos and dual-booting. I do not see anywhere on that page where it discusses doing a full install.

Comment: @jay when you look at the above page the second and third picture clearly show *install*.